# Is it possible to find $n$ from the sum forming a polynomial?

Tags: summation

How does one solve for $n$ in:

$100000 = \sum\limits_{x=1}^n 1020.2065\ x^{-0.3431}$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: What have you tried? There's, `Solve`, `Sum`... please post your attempt otherwise this is a very narrow question liable to be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
eq = 100000 == Sum[1020.2065 (x^(-0.3431)), {x, 1, n}];
Solve[%, n]

 (* {{n -> 575.2486665048036}} *)
```

Comment: A teeny modification to @Nasser's fine solution:  First divide both sides by 1020.2065 and then `Solve[98.0194 == Sum[x^(-0.3431), {x, 1, n}], n] // Quiet` yields $n \rightarrow 575.249$.

Comment: Thank you this helps a lot!

I assume you used Mathematica...

Comment: @user27200 `I assume you used Mathematica` Yes, these are Mathematica commands.

Comment: @Nasser I suppose one ought to point out that the computation shows that there is, in fact, **no** solution.

Comment: @MichaelE2 yes, no solution in integers (since n is an index, it has to be integer).

Comment: Yes, just what I was thinking.  Kind of a strange problem.